# Python Queue module get stuck

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python2.7, when using `Queue` module:

```
q = Queue.PriorityQueue(maxsize=3)
q.put((1,'foo'))
q.put((2,'bar'))
q.put((3,'baz'))
q.put((4,'boo'))   # on purpose
```

Then the script get stuck. I also tried in Ipython, it gets stuck when I put the 4th item. Why is this happening? And how do I correctly use `PriorityQueue` to create a given size priority queue.

Comment: You are limiting ur Queue "maxsize=3"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [`Queue` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.put):

> Queue.put(item[, block[, timeout]])
>
> Put item into the queue. **If optional args block is true and timeout is
>   None (the default), block if necessary until a free slot is available.**
>   If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and
>   raises the Full exception if no free slot was available within that
>   time. Otherwise (block is false), put an item on the queue if a free
>   slot is immediately available, else raise the Full exception (timeout
>   is ignored in that case).

Comment: The system asked to accept right answer after 10 min.